# Python render eli5 explanation to image

Tags: python, ipython, eli5

I'm using the [eli5](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) library to explain a sklearn decision tree in a Jupyter notebook by calling `eli5.show_weights(...)`. The output is an `IPython.core.display.HTML` element that I can display inside the notebook with `IPython.display.display(explanation)`, but how can I render the picture of the decision tree that this draws as an image (or pdf) so that I can use it somewhere else?